# Definition of hidden regularity

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes

I am reading a paper about existence and uniqueness of local strong solutions for an equation. The authors said that they prove new "hidden regularity" results for some equation, and by this they expressed that the solution belongs to a new functional space.

I don't know the definition of "hidden regularity" and I have searched about it but I can't find it.

Is there anybody who know the definition of "hidden regularity"?

Comment: I guess they took the usual "let's find weak solutions to the problem,then let's see if they can be made 'stronger'" approach. I think "hidden regularity" refers to this.

Comment: @Andrew But there is nothing mentioned about weak solution in this paper!